# Alpha Vantage API not working for Brazilian stocks

Tags: stock, alpha-vantage

I am trying to fetch Brazilian stock prices with [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co) API. For this example, I'll talk about PETR4.
I have used Alpha Vantage [Search Endpoint](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=PETR4&apikey=$). It returns the symbol of the currency:

> {
>       "bestMatches": [
>           {
>               "1. symbol": "PETR4.SAO", ...
>       } }

Nevertheless, the [TIME_SERIES_DAILY endpoint](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=PETR4.SAO&apikey=$) (or any other as a matter of fact) returns an error:

> "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the
>   documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for
>   TIME_SERIES_DAILY."

Notice that it works [with GOOG ticker](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=GOOG&apikey=$), for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=PETR4.SA&apikey=xxx

For all tickers from Alpha Vantage, you need to try the "ticker.exchange". PETR4 is listed on the B3 exchange.

However, a number of Brazilian tickers were listed on the [Sao Paolo exchange](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sao-paolo-stock-exchange-sao-.sa.asp), which had the suffix `.SA`. This exchange has since merged with the [B3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B3_(stock_exchange)) exchange, and it's suffix has not been changed. A good reference can be seen on the [yahoo finance entry of the same ticker](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PETR4.SA?p=PETR4.SA&.tsrc=fin-srch).

Comment: The relevant point here is that there is no intraday Brazilian stock market data in the alpha vantage api, only daily ones.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue. This is the outcome when I pass `function=SYMBOL_SEARCH` and `keywords=TOTVS`, for instance:

> {'1. symbol': 'TOTS3.SAO',
> '2. name': 'TOTVS S.A',

However, when trying to reach `function=OVERVIEW` for symbol `TOTS3.SAO`, the query returns empty. Same is true for `TOTS3`, `TOTS.SA`, `TOTS%2ESAO`, `TOTS%2ESA`, `TOTS\.SA` and `TOTS\.SAO`

Answer (score 0):

For some endpoints like TIME_SERIES_DAILY the symbols are like:
PETR4.SA.SAO
VALE3.SA.SAO